# Flutter: how to read a csv from assets

Tags: csv, flutter, decode

I was messing with the `csv 4.1.0` package and `csv_reader` but I can't figure out how to read a csv :c
Is there any easy way/recipe to implement a "reader" and get a kind of list of lists?

I've tried
`List<List<dynamic>> data = const CsvToListConverter().convert("assets/csv/name.csv");`
then I do `print(data)` and I get `flutter: [[assets/csv/name.csv]]`

Note: I have added my csv as a dependency in the pubspec.yaml file in assets

I want to get this csv: https://gist.github.com/armgilles/194bcff35001e7eb53a2a8b441e8b2c6

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

include this in your pubspec.yaml:
`csv: ^4.1.0` (The Current Version)
You can use the package import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
Inside you have a method called CsvToListConverter(), using this you can convert your CSV data to a nice list.

```
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
...
List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues = const CsvToListConverter().convert(data);
```